# IOS Google admob appdelegate code is deprecated for splash interstitial

Tags: ios, google-ad-manager

I am using IOS Google Admob SDK 6.11.1 and Xcode 5.1.

[image: my sample code warning]

If I thought `loadrequest` is replacement for `loadanddisplayrequest` but its not.

```
[splashInterstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Because intertitial never appears by using loadrequest only.

**loadAndDisplayRequest** this method is working but I want to know whats the replacement for this deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `presentFromRootViewController:` after you've received the interstitial:

```
#pragma mark - GADInterstitialDelegate
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(DFPInterstitial *)ad
{
    [splashInterstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in appdelegate .it's working for me.

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {


        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request]; // here you need to crate object of GADRequest
        interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
        interstitial_.adUnitID =@"ca-app-pub-43434/343434";
        interstitial_.delegate = self;
    //    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    //                           @"MY_SIMULATOR_IDENTIFIER",
    //                           @"fbb99fa8c725017137fb191a20aa342491b82a37",
    //                           nil];

        [interstitial_ loadRequest:request];

    }


    - (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {


        NSLog(@"==%@",[error localizedDescription]);


    }

    -(void)interstitialWillPresentScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad{
        NSLog(@"on screen");
    }
    - (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {

        //   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

        [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];


        // [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];


    }
```